# Add extra left and right offset for chart

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I need something similar to `extraLeftOffset` and `extraRightOffset` but I need this offset to be visible only when you reach the beginning or the end of a chart. In other words, I need visually to show beginning and end of a chart when scrolling.

For example, when you scroll to the latest chart entry, the right offset is visible but left offset is not.

[image: chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.

```
lineChartView.setDragOffsetX(22.0)
```